# Have made the month as factor but failed to show the right month order in ggplot2

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, web-scraping

I attempt to scrap a wikipedia table and make a graph, as a practice of scrapping and regex and ggplot.

There is a tough problem in making the month the x-axis.

1. Is there an easy way to recognize Chinese unit of month (i.e. 月) so that the month order can be indicated in ggplot2?
2. Alternatively, I tried using the English naming, but after numerous attempts, including using `factor` to make sure the month order, I still obtained a graph with the month in alphabetical order, i.e. April, August, December, February...May I know where the problem is?

And, 3) how to use a numeric naming instead?

Thanks for your reply. The following is my code.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
library(netstat)

selenium()

selenium_object <- selenium(retcommand = TRUE, check = F)
selenium_object

binman::list_versions("chromedriver")

#start the server
rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                          chromever = "117.0.5938.92",
                          verbose = F,
                          port = free_port())

#create a client object
remDr <- rs_driver_object$client

#open a browser
remDr$open()

#navigate to website
remDr$navigate("https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%B2%99%E7%94%B0_(%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF)")

library(XML)
library(stringr)

webpage_text <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
tables <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(webpage_text),"//table")
df <- readHTMLTable(tables[[3]], Encoding("UTF-8"))


colnames(df) <- df[2,]
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
df <- df[c(-1, -2, -10),-1]

df1 <- df
for (i in 1:6){
  for (j in 1:13){
  df1[i,j] = str_extract(df1[i,j], "\\d+([.,]\\d+)?+(?<!\\()")
  }
}

df2 <- subset(df1, select = -ncol(df1)) %>% slice(1:(n()-2))
colnames(df2) <- sub("月", "", colnames(df2))


library(lubridate)

#colnames(df2) <- lubridate::parse_date_time(colnames(df2), '%m')
#colnames(df2)

#colnames(df2) <- format(as.Date(as.numeric(colnames(df2))),"%b")

colnames(df2) <- month.abb[as.numeric(colnames(df2))]

colnames(df2) <- factor(colnames(df2), levels = month.abb)

df3 <- df2

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df4 <- df3 %>% group_by(row.names(df3)) %>% pivot_longer(cols = 1:ncol(df3))

df4$value <- as.numeric(df4$value)

library(ggplot2)

g1 <- ggplot(df4) + geom_line(aes(x=df4$name , y = df4$value,  group = df4$`row.names(df3)`)) + labs(x = "Month", y = "degree C")
g1
```

The datafile is here: https://github.com/ronzenith/spss-for-r/blob/main/df.rds

```html
<div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow: auto; height: 495px; width: 100%; position: relative;"><table id="rsGridData" class="dataTable autoSize no-footer" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="rsGridData_info" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 290px;"><thead>   <tr id="data_cols" role="row" style="height: 0px;"><th title="row names" class="first-child sorting_asc" aria-controls="rsGridData" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20.4375px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label=": activate to sort column descending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;"><div class="headerCell"><div></div><div class="resizer" data-col="0"></div></div></div></th><th title="column 1: character" class="sorting" aria-controls="rsGridData" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 117.719px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="row.names(df3): activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;"><div class="headerCell"><div>row.names(df3)</div><div class="resizer" data-col="1"></div></div></div></th><th title="column 2: character" class="sorting" aria-controls="rsGridData" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 54.1875px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="name: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;"><div class="headerCell"><div>name</div><div class="resizer" data-col="2"></div></div></div></th><th title="column 3: numeric with range 0 - 40" class="sorting" aria-controls="rsGridData" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 53.6562px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" aria-label="value: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;"><div class="headerCell"><div>value</div><div class="resizer" data-col="3"></div></div></div></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr data-row="0" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="1">1</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-01-01">0-01-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="27.6">27.6</div></td></tr><tr data-row="1" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="2">2</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-02-01">0-02-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="28.6">28.6</div></td></tr><tr data-row="2" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="3">3</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-03-01">0-03-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="31.8">31.8</div></td></tr><tr data-row="3" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="4">4</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-04-01">0-04-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="33.0">33.0</div></td></tr><tr data-row="4" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="5">5</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-05-01">0-05-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="36.6">36.6</div></td></tr><tr data-row="5" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="6">6</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-06-01">0-06-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="36.4">36.4</div></td></tr><tr data-row="6" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="7">7</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-07-01">0-07-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="37.5">37.5</div></td></tr><tr data-row="7" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="8">8</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-08-01">0-08-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="38.1">38.1</div></td></tr><tr data-row="8" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="9">9</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-09-01">0-09-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="36.5">36.5</div></td></tr><tr data-row="9" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="10">10</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-10-01">0-10-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="35.1">35.1</div></td></tr><tr data-row="10" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="11">11</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-11-01">0-11-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="31.8">31.8</div></td></tr><tr data-row="11" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="12">12</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最高溫 °C（°F）">歷史最高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-12-01">0-12-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="28.9">28.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="12" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="13">13</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-01-01">0-01-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="19.3">19.3</div></td></tr><tr data-row="13" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="14">14</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-02-01">0-02-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="19.8">19.8</div></td></tr><tr data-row="14" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="15">15</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-03-01">0-03-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="22.1">22.1</div></td></tr><tr data-row="15" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="16">16</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-04-01">0-04-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="25.7">25.7</div></td></tr><tr data-row="16" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="17">17</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-05-01">0-05-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="29.0">29.0</div></td></tr><tr data-row="17" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="18">18</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-06-01">0-06-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="30.8">30.8</div></td></tr><tr data-row="18" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="19">19</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-07-01">0-07-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="31.9">31.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="19" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="20">20</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-08-01">0-08-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="31.9">31.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="20" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="21">21</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-09-01">0-09-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="31.1">31.1</div></td></tr><tr data-row="21" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="22">22</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-10-01">0-10-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="28.5">28.5</div></td></tr><tr data-row="22" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="23">23</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-11-01">0-11-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="24.9">24.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="23" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="24">24</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均高溫 °C（°F）">平均高溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-12-01">0-12-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="20.9">20.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="24" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="25">25</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-01-01">0-01-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="15.8">15.8</div></td></tr><tr data-row="25" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="26">26</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-02-01">0-02-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="16.5">16.5</div></td></tr><tr data-row="26" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="27">27</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-03-01">0-03-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="19.1">19.1</div></td></tr><tr data-row="27" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="28">28</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-04-01">0-04-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="22.6">22.6</div></td></tr><tr data-row="28" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="29">29</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-05-01">0-05-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="26.1">26.1</div></td></tr><tr data-row="29" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="30">30</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-06-01">0-06-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="28.1">28.1</div></td></tr><tr data-row="30" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="31">31</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-07-01">0-07-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="28.9">28.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="31" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="32">32</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-08-01">0-08-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="28.6">28.6</div></td></tr><tr data-row="32" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="33">33</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-09-01">0-09-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="27.8">27.8</div></td></tr><tr data-row="33" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="34">34</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-10-01">0-10-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="25.2">25.2</div></td></tr><tr data-row="34" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="35">35</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-11-01">0-11-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="21.5">21.5</div></td></tr><tr data-row="35" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="36">36</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="日均氣溫 °C（°F）">日均氣溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-12-01">0-12-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="17.2">17.2</div></td></tr><tr data-row="36" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="37">37</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-01-01">0-01-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="12.9">12.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="37" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="38">38</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-02-01">0-02-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="13.9">13.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="38" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="39">39</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-03-01">0-03-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="16.7">16.7</div></td></tr><tr data-row="39" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="40">40</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-04-01">0-04-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="20.2">20.2</div></td></tr><tr data-row="40" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="41">41</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-05-01">0-05-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="23.7">23.7</div></td></tr><tr data-row="41" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="42">42</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-06-01">0-06-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="25.8">25.8</div></td></tr><tr data-row="42" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="43">43</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-07-01">0-07-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="26.3">26.3</div></td></tr><tr data-row="43" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="44">44</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-08-01">0-08-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="26.0">26.0</div></td></tr><tr data-row="44" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="45">45</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-09-01">0-09-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="25.2">25.2</div></td></tr><tr data-row="45" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="46">46</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-10-01">0-10-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="22.6">22.6</div></td></tr><tr data-row="46" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="47">47</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-11-01">0-11-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="18.7">18.7</div></td></tr><tr data-row="47" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="48">48</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="平均低溫 °C（°F）">平均低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-12-01">0-12-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="14.1">14.1</div></td></tr><tr data-row="48" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="49">49</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-01-01">0-01-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="2.9">2.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="49" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="50">50</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-02-01">0-02-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="4.0">4.0</div></td></tr><tr data-row="50" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="51">51</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-03-01">0-03-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="4.4">4.4</div></td></tr><tr data-row="51" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="52">52</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-04-01">0-04-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="10.2">10.2</div></td></tr><tr data-row="52" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="53">53</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-05-01">0-05-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="15.3">15.3</div></td></tr><tr data-row="53" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="54">54</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-06-01">0-06-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="19.9">19.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="54" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="55">55</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-07-01">0-07-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="21.3">21.3</div></td></tr><tr data-row="55" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="56">56</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-08-01">0-08-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="22.1">22.1</div></td></tr><tr data-row="56" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="57">57</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-09-01">0-09-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="19.9">19.9</div></td></tr><tr data-row="57" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="58">58</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-10-01">0-10-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="14.4">14.4</div></td></tr><tr data-row="58" role="row" class="odd"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="59">59</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-11-01">0-11-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="6.3">6.3</div></td></tr><tr data-row="59" role="row" class="even"><td class="first-child sorting sorting_1"><div class="textCell" title="60">60</div></td><td><div class="textCell largeCell" title="歷史最低溫 °C（°F）">歷史最低溫&nbsp;°C（°F）</div></td><td><div class="textCell" title="0-12-01">0-12-01</div></td><td><div class="numberCell" title="4.8">4.8</div></td></tr></tbody></table><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1380px;"></div></div>
```

Comment: Hi @ronzenith - I think you'll get better answers if you post the data frame that you are trying to plot, i.e. the output of `dput(df4))` (which I know from your previous question is not a large data frame), rather than expecting people to try to scrape the website.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your interest. The file is in my Github now: https://github.com/ronzenith/spss-for-r/blob/main/df.rds

Comment: thanks but I'm reluctant to open a link to a binary file and I suspect others will be as well. Also see [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code). Your question loses future value if that link disappears at some point. Better to include the data in the question by copying and pasting the output of `dput(df4))`.

Comment: Sam, I've tried pasting the code in html here. See if it's better for you and fellow users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included at the end the data in the form that I meant in the comments. In terms of this specific question, your problem is that your `name` column is not a date and needs to be. It's a yearly average so it doesn't actually correspond to a specific year, but we can make it `2023` as a dummy and then not plot the year.

```r
## Make the month a date
df4 <- within(
    df4,
    {   
        # Make month a date
        month <- as.Date(gsub("^0-", "2023-", name))
        # Also tidy up the labels abit
        metric <- sub("°C（°F）", "", `row.names(df3)`)
    }
)
```

Now draw the plot. Note that `scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")` tells `ggplot` to only label the month and not the year. Here is a [useful list](https://devhints.io/datetime) of the various date format abbreviations and their meaning.

```r
ggplot(df4) +
    geom_line(
        aes(x = month, y = value, group = metric, color = metric)
    ) +
    labs(x = "Month", y = "degree C") +
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Output:

[image]

#### Data

```r
df4 <- structure(list(1:60, `row.names(df3)` = c("歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最高溫 °C（°F）", "平均高溫 °C（°F）", 
"平均高溫 °C（°F）", "平均高溫 °C（°F）", "平均高溫 °C（°F）", 
"平均高溫 °C（°F）", "平均高溫 °C（°F）", "平均高溫 °C（°F）", 
"平均高溫 °C（°F）", "平均高溫 °C（°F）", "平均高溫 °C（°F）", 
"平均高溫 °C（°F）", "平均高溫 °C（°F）", "日均氣溫 °C（°F）", 
"日均氣溫 °C（°F）", "日均氣溫 °C（°F）", "日均氣溫 °C（°F）", 
"日均氣溫 °C（°F）", "日均氣溫 °C（°F）", "日均氣溫 °C（°F）", 
"日均氣溫 °C（°F）", "日均氣溫 °C（°F）", "日均氣溫 °C（°F）", 
"日均氣溫 °C（°F）", "日均氣溫 °C（°F）", "平均低溫 °C（°F）", 
"平均低溫 °C（°F）", "平均低溫 °C（°F）", "平均低溫 °C（°F）", 
"平均低溫 °C（°F）", "平均低溫 °C（°F）", "平均低溫 °C（°F）", 
"平均低溫 °C（°F）", "平均低溫 °C（°F）", "平均低溫 °C（°F）", 
"平均低溫 °C（°F）", "平均低溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", "歷史最低溫 °C（°F）", 
"歷史最低溫 °C（°F）"), name = c("0-01-01", "0-02-01", 
"0-03-01", "0-04-01", "0-05-01", "0-06-01", "0-07-01", "0-08-01", 
"0-09-01", "0-10-01", "0-11-01", "0-12-01", "0-01-01", "0-02-01", 
"0-03-01", "0-04-01", "0-05-01", "0-06-01", "0-07-01", "0-08-01", 
"0-09-01", "0-10-01", "0-11-01", "0-12-01", "0-01-01", "0-02-01", 
"0-03-01", "0-04-01", "0-05-01", "0-06-01", "0-07-01", "0-08-01", 
"0-09-01", "0-10-01", "0-11-01", "0-12-01", "0-01-01", "0-02-01", 
"0-03-01", "0-04-01", "0-05-01", "0-06-01", "0-07-01", "0-08-01", 
"0-09-01", "0-10-01", "0-11-01", "0-12-01", "0-01-01", "0-02-01", 
"0-03-01", "0-04-01", "0-05-01", "0-06-01", "0-07-01", "0-08-01", 
"0-09-01", "0-10-01", "0-11-01", "0-12-01"), value = c(27.6, 
28.6, 31.8, 33, 36.6, 36.4, 37.5, 38.1, 36.5, 35.1, 31.8, 28.9, 
19.3, 19.8, 22.1, 25.7, 29, 30.8, 31.9, 31.9, 31.1, 28.5, 24.9, 
20.9, 15.8, 16.5, 19.1, 22.6, 26.1, 28.1, 28.9, 28.6, 27.8, 25.2, 
21.5, 17.2, 12.9, 13.9, 16.7, 20.2, 23.7, 25.8, 26.3, 26, 25.2, 
22.6, 18.7, 14.1, 2.9, 4, 4.4, 10.2, 15.3, 19.9, 21.3, 22.1, 
19.9, 14.4, 6.3, 4.8)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for your help. I've never seen a function //within// before. I'll learn it later.

Comment: I've also just come up with a stupid conversion of the month order: 

df2 <- subset(df1, select = -ncol(df1)) %>% slice(1:(n()-2)) %>% setNames(as.numeric(c(1:12)))
colnames(df2) <- lubridate::parse_date_time(colnames(df2), '%m')
colnames(df2) <- gsub('^0-', '', colnames(df2))
colnames(df2) <- gsub('-01$', '', colnames(df2))
df3 <- df2
df4 <- df3 %>% group_by(row.names(df3)) %>% pivot_longer(cols = 1:ncol(df3))
colnames(df4) <- c("項目", "月份", "溫度") 

df4$value <- as.numeric(df4$value)

g1 <- ggplot(df4) + geom_line(aes(x=月份 , y = 溫度,  group = 項目, color = 項目))
g1